# Google cloud messaging by fetching from database

Tags: php, android, android-notifications

I'm working on getting news from server into the android application. Now I'm thinking of getting push notification using google cloud messaging. What I'm trying in my application is

1. Check regularly in server if there are any new data added to database.
2. if yes then make a push notification.

I'm not seeing any tutorial which does this thing. I only found android code. Please help me on this. I'm newbie to this concept.

Thanks.

Comment: Which part of this are you having a problem with?

Comment: @Anigel: in php. I have datas to be displayed in listview. But if new data is uploaded into database table, it should show a new push notification. I don't know how to checkout for "see if new data is there, if 'yes' make a push notification."

Comment: Something has to update the data. So when it does that, you know there is new data, either that or store the old data somewhere if you are not already doing that and compare new data to it. if it does not match then there is new data

Comment: The code where you are entering a news into database, there you may write the code to send the notification (news data + API Key) to GCM every time you enter a news. The GCM will automatically send it on the SENDER_ID (Of your App). You may then receive those using a Broadcast Receiver in you Android app.

PS: Don't forget to register the app on gcm and get a regId.

Answer (score 0):

You have to options for this:

1.. To contact your server from the app periodically and check if there are any new notifications. If so you get the data and show it to the user.

-You can do this by scheduling an alarm, maybe once a day, that starts a service that does the server checking and notifying the user. (this can be an ok solution if you know that new notifications will appear at fixed time intervals, i used it for an app that has show weekly news each Friday at noon)

2.. Google Cloud Messaging for Android

Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device, and also to receive messages from devices on the same connection. The GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery to the target Android application running on the target device. GCM is completely free no matter how big your messaging needs are, and there are no quotas.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

I would recommend this if you want to be able to send notifications to users at any given time.

You have nice tutorials on developer.android, its safe and reliable and you will have complete control over the process.

I am currently working on implementing option 2, so i can update my experience on it once its done.

and here is an implementation tutorial on this one: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Comment: The first method you suggested, I already implemented that one. But I'm thinking of using GCM for the next step. One question is in my mind. Who will check for new update in database. Whether is the GCM or the php file that is in server. Can GCM cloud server access my database table directly?

Comment: Your server should do the checking, and when there are new updates it should notify the GCM cloud server to push notifications to users.

Comment: I dont know how often will you be updating the database? if its a few times a week, then you can manually run the php script, after updating the db, that will notify GCM....if its more you can use cron jobs maybe, but i am going for a java web server since it can listen for changes in the database and do everything automatically...(and i'll have db updates a few times a day)